# How to perform conditional merging of pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, `df1`:

```
group    value
g1       A
g1       B
g1       C
g1       D
g2       B
g2       C
g2       E
g3       A
g3       D
g3       E
g4       B
g4       D
...
```

and `df2`:

```
value1   value2
A        B
A        C
B        C
B        D
...
```

I would like to merge `df1` and `df2` by merging columns `value` with both `value1` and `value2`, namely:

```
group    value1    value2
g1       A         B
g1       A         C
g1       B         C
g2       B         C
g1       B         D
g4       B         D
...
```

As shown, `group` illustrates two columns `value1` and `value2` only if the two values simultaneously corresponds to the same group in `df1`.

```
df = df1.merge(df2, left_on='value', right_on='value1', how='inner')
df = df.merge(df2, left_on='value', right_on='value2', how='inner')
df = df.drop(['value'], axis=1)
```

The problem is, my actual dataframes `df1` and `df2` are quite large and every time I try to run the code, the session crashes (Not to mention, not quite sure if my code is correct to begin with).

Any idea how to optimize this process (and to confirm whether my approach is correct)?

Comment: Your second merge statement should be :
df = df.merge(df2, left_on='value', right_on='value2', how='inner')

Answer (score 2):

What is the need for the second merge? Isn't one enough?

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', left_on=['value'], right_on=['value1']).drop(columns=['value'])
print(df)

  group value1 value2
0    g1      A      B
1    g1      A      C
2    g3      A      B
3    g3      A      C
4    g1      B      C
5    g1      B      D
6    g2      B      C
7    g2      B      D
8    g4      B      C
9    g4      B      D
```

Comment: The problem is, if I do this, I would get some "incorrectly merged" rows. For example, the third and fourth rows (`g3`, `A`, `B`) (`g3`, `A`, `C`) are incorrect, as `A` corresponds to `g3` but neither `B` nor `C` in `df1`.